# problem changing png color automatically after changing the src of this png

Tags: javascript, jquery, png, color-picker

Here is what I'm trying to achieve : A product designer where I can change the src of an image (I got a collection of 8bits black & white pngs) and choose the color of this png.

I'm using jQuery and a color picker to change the color of the png, that works great with the following function :

```
var changeIconColor = (function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), // shared instance
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // set image pixel size and hex color
    color = '00ff00';
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 1000;

    function desaturate() {
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
            pixels = imageData.data,
            i, l, r, g, b, a, average;

        for (i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i += 4) {
            a = pixels[i + 3];
            if (a === 0) {
                continue;
            } // skip if pixel is transparent

            r = pixels[i];
            g = pixels[i + 1];
            b = pixels[i + 2];

            average = (r + g + b) / 3 >>> 0; // quick floor
            pixels[i] = pixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 2] = average;
        }

        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

    function colorize(color, alpha) {
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
        context.globalAlpha = alpha;
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // reset
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
    }

    return function (iconElement, color, alpha) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(iconElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        desaturate();
        colorize(color, alpha);
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
    };

}());
```

I'm calling it when changing the color on the color picker :

```
$('#mask_insert_1').each(function () {
    this.src = changeIconColor(this, $( "#colorpicker_insert_1" ).val(), '1');
});
```

This changes the black pixels of the png to the choosen color. That works great.

Then I have another function that changes the src of this png :

```
$("#select_insert_1").change(function(){
    $("#mask_insert_1").show(); 
    $('#mask_insert_1').attr('src','assets/inserts/'+$("#select_insert_1").val()+'.png');
});
```

When I select another option in my select, it updates to src.
That also works ok.

BUT... When I select a new PNG, it's displayed with black pixels. That's ok, it should be like that. But I'd like to add a line of code to update the color when the src changes.

I have another function that can update the color of the png manualy when I push a button and I've tried to add it inside the "change select" function but it doesn't work...

```
$('#mask_insert_1').each(function () { this.src = changeIconColor(this, $( "#colorpicker_insert_1" ).val(), '1'); });
```

Where Am I wrong ?

Many thanks for reading me, more thanks if you can help.
AP

Comment: Can you please put your code in running snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change src of an image, the image is not updated immediately. What you need to do is add `onload` event listener to the image and update it's color from there.

```js
document.getElementById("colorpicker_insert_1").value = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16).padStart(6, "0");


var changeIconColor = (function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), // shared instance
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // set image pixel size and hex color
    color = '00ff00';
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    function desaturate() {
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
            pixels = imageData.data,
            i, l, r, g, b, a, average;

        for (i = 0, l = pixels.length; i < l; i += 4) {
            a = pixels[i + 3];
            if (a === 0) {
                continue;
            } // skip if pixel is transparent

            r = pixels[i];
            g = pixels[i + 1];
            b = pixels[i + 2];

            average = (r + g + b) / 3 >>> 0; // quick floor
            pixels[i] = pixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 2] = average;
        }

        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

    function colorize(color, alpha) {
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
        context.globalAlpha = alpha;
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // reset
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        context.globalAlpha = 1;
    }

    return function (iconElement, color, alpha) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(iconElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        desaturate();
        colorize(color, alpha);
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
    };

}());

$("#select_insert_1").change(function(){
    $("#mask_insert_1").show(); 
    $('#mask_insert_1').attr('src', $("#select_insert_1").val());

/* show original image */
document.getElementById("img").src = $("#select_insert_1").val();

});

$('#mask_insert_1').each(function () {
    const img = this;
  let src;

  /* add onload event listener */
  img.onload = e =>
  {
    /* do nothing if image generated by changeIconColor() */
    if (img.src !== src)
      img.src = src = changeIconColor(img, $( "#colorpicker_insert_1" ).val(), '1');
  }
  /* change color now */
  img.onload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_insert_1">
<option value="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">img 1</option>
<option value="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7">img 2</option>
<option value="invalid image data">img 3</option>
</select>
<input id="colorpicker_insert_1" oninput='$("#select_insert_1").trigger("change")'>

<img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">

<img id="mask_insert_1" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

Comment: Wow. Many thanks it's working !
But I think the listener won't stop, the page keep loading...

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new here, I've been a lurker for years :/

Comment: Your code works great but the browser keeps loading until I stop the page's loading. 
Is the event listener always active ? Would there be a way to prevent that ?
I've seen on your exemple that it's not happening :/

Comment: That's my bad, my code also had this issue, but since images are local, it wasn't noticeable. I've updated the code.